# SDL Convert pixel format

Tags: sdl2, pixel

I have two pixes stored in a 32 bit unsigned integer (4 bytes per pixel, using SDL's types for convenience):

```
Uint32 pixel1;        // Source pixel, format: SDL_PIXELFORMAT_BGRA8888
Uint32 pixel2_format; // Format of the pixel2 (can change)
Uint32 pixel2;        // Destination pixel
```

How can I convert the format from `pixel1` to `pixel2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, you are asking how to extract bites of one bitmask and set it on the other, for example :

```
const uint mask = 0x000000FF; //single color mask
const uint aOff = 3 * 8; //offsets of colors from the end for ARGB
const uint rOff = 2 * 8;
const uint gOff = 1 * 8;
const uint bOff = 0 * 8;

uint pixel1 = 0xFFFF0000; //red in ARGB
uint pixel2 = 0x0;
pixel2 |= ((pixel1 & (mask << bOff)) >> bOff) << (3 * 8);//set b
pixel2 |= ((pixel1 & (mask << gOff)) >> gOff) << (2 * 8);//set g
pixel2 |= ((pixel1 & (mask << rOff)) >> rOff) << (1 * 8);//set r
pixel2 |= ((pixel1 & (mask << aOff)) >> aOff) << (0 * 8);//set a
```

first, you create appropriate mask `(mask << bOff)` by shifting single color mask to correct position (alternatively, because it is static value tied to source pixel format so you can pre-compute it), then you extract all bits of the color channel by `pixel1 & mask` and shift them to get the value `value >> bOff`. After that you shift the value to its correct position in BGRA8888 format `value << (pos * 8)` and last you *or* it with zeroed BGRA8888 pixed `pixel2 |= shiftedValue`.
 
You can skip some shifting if you know the formats in advance and hardcode it.

Comment: Don't you need to bitwise OR the components of the pixel? Instead of AND?

Comment: @Xriuk yes, sorry there was a mistake, last operation should be OR. (alternatively, setting default value of pixel2 to ones - 0xFFFFFFFF would also work)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had to add this answer because I found something on my own:
Basically there is this function [`SDL_ConvertPixels()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertPixels) *hidden in the wiki* and it's located inside `SDL_surface.h` header and not inside `SDL_pixels.h` (mystery...). This function converts pixels from any supported [PixelFormat](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormatEnum) to another one.

Plus, **a suggestion for everybody**: When working with bits, remember to check the [endianess of your machine](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryEndian) or you'll get pixels with inverted colors (like I did...)!